# Intellij IDEA, control page up, page down scroll size

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-13, intellij-14

I am not satisfied with the scrolling behaviour in intellij for page up, page down. It doesn't feel right. It always feels as if I get out of the scope.

Is it possible to adjust the scroll size of page up, page down? Perhaps to half a page or similar.

Comment: Define "scope".  What do you want to happen when you scroll/page up and down?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with that plugin? Care to share?

Comment: No, not yet. Other plugins have been added though. This one not yet, but it is annoying me on a daily basis. Another annoyance is the way ctrl left selects words, never right.

Comment: I issued a feature request for scrolling up/down *half* a page. Please vote for it in case you miss it too: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-175397

Comment: @Rotareti Thank you! It is so annoying still, I am thinking of developing a plugin for this. It kills me everyday.

Comment: If you are on a mac you can get this behaviour globally, not just in Intellij, which is the solution i ended up with. Smooth too.

Comment: @mmm - for the mac users out there with the same problem, would you mind sharing how you got this working globally?

Comment: @AaronV Karabiner. Add a complex rule to scroll on pagedown instead.

Comment: @AaronV here is one for page_down ... https://hastebin.com/ ... note, i click randomly after since it is scrolling .. for global use, you do not need to click. So other rules unless bundle_identifiers.

Comment: @AaronV also recommend Mos application to smooth scroll control.

Comment: @AaronV hastebin acting up, so I added a new answer with code instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since many are inquiring about this, for **mac users** this can be controlled globally instead by instead scrolling on page up/down using **karabiner** application and adding the following complex rule:

```
{
    "description": "mmm.karabiner.page.up.down.to.scroll",
    "manipulators": [
        {
            "conditions": [
                {
                    "bundle_identifiers": [
                        "^net.java.openjdk.cmd",
                        "^com.jetbrains.intellij"
                    ],
                    "type": "frontmost_application_if"
                }
            ],
            "from": {
                "key_code": "page_up"
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "mouse_key": {
                        "vertical_wheel": -51
                    }
                }
            ],
            "to_delayed_action": {
                "to_if_invoked": [
                    {
                        "pointing_button": "button1"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "type": "basic"
        },
        {
            "conditions": [
                {
                    "bundle_identifiers": [
                        "^net.java.openjdk.cmd",
                        "^com.jetbrains.intellij"
                    ],
                    "type": "frontmost_application_unless"
                }
            ],
            "from": {
                "key_code": "page_up"
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "mouse_key": {
                        "vertical_wheel": -51
                    }
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        },
        {
            "conditions": [
                {
                    "bundle_identifiers": [
                        "^net.java.openjdk.cmd",
                        "^com.jetbrains.intellij"
                    ],
                    "type": "frontmost_application_if"
                }
            ],
            "from": {
                "key_code": "up_arrow",
                "modifiers": {
                    "mandatory": [
                        "fn"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "mouse_key": {
                        "vertical_wheel": -51
                    }
                }
            ],
            "to_delayed_action": {
                "to_if_invoked": [
                    {
                        "pointing_button": "button1"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "type": "basic"
        },
        {
            "conditions": [
                {
                    "bundle_identifiers": [
                        "^net.java.openjdk.cmd",
                        "^com.jetbrains.intellij"
                    ],
                    "type": "frontmost_application_unless"
                }
            ],
            "from": {
                "key_code": "up_arrow",
                "modifiers": {
                    "mandatory": [
                        "fn"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "mouse_key": {
                        "vertical_wheel": -51
                    }
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        },
        {
            "conditions": [
                {
                    "bundle_identifiers": [
                        "^net.java.openjdk.cmd",
                        "^com.jetbrains.intellij"
                    ],
                    "type": "frontmost_application_if"
                }
            ],
            "from": {
                "key_code": "page_down"
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "mouse_key": {
                        "vertical_wheel": 51
                    }
                }
            ],
            "to_delayed_action": {
                "to_if_invoked": [
                    {
                        "pointing_button": "button1"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "type": "basic"
        },
        {
            "conditions": [
                {
                    "bundle_identifiers": [
                        "^net.java.openjdk.cmd",
                        "^com.jetbrains.intellij"
                    ],
                    "type": "frontmost_application_unless"
                }
            ],
            "from": {
                "key_code": "page_down"
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "mouse_key": {
                        "vertical_wheel": 51
                    }
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        },
        {
            "conditions": [
                {
                    "bundle_identifiers": [
                        "^net.java.openjdk.cmd",
                        "^com.jetbrains.intellij"
                    ],
                    "type": "frontmost_application_if"
                }
            ],
            "from": {
                "key_code": "down_arrow",
                "modifiers": {
                    "mandatory": [
                        "fn"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "mouse_key": {
                        "vertical_wheel": 51
                    }
                }
            ],
            "to_delayed_action": {
                "to_if_invoked": [
                    {
                        "pointing_button": "button1"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "type": "basic"
        },
        {
            "conditions": [
                {
                    "bundle_identifiers": [
                        "^net.java.openjdk.cmd",
                        "^com.jetbrains.intellij"
                    ],
                    "type": "frontmost_application_unless"
                }
            ],
            "from": {
                "key_code": "down_arrow",
                "modifiers": {
                    "mandatory": [
                        "fn"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "mouse_key": {
                        "vertical_wheel": 51
                    }
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        }
    ]
},
```

Also do note, to get smooth scrolling, consider down loading **Mos application** and adjust the preferences if desired.

https://mos.caldis.me/

This might have other consequences on your Mac so you might need to have to adjust other things since your page_up/down is no longer a page_up/down **but mouse scrolls** instead.

Comment: This does not answer the question of how to do this on Intellij. Setting this answer as the accepted answer to the question is misleading.

Comment: @AndréC.Andersen there is a plugin for this now.

Answer (score 5):

I had taken @yole's answer and implemented all of the actions he had described in a separate plugin:

> There is no way to control this through the settings. What you can do is write a plugin that performs scrolling in the way that you prefer. It's fairly easy: all you need to do is copy the existing 
>   PageUpAction/PageDownAction classes and the methods they call 
>   (EditorActionUtil.moveCaretPageUp/Down) to scroll by as much as you want.

This plugin implements new actions "Partial Page Up" and "Partial Page Down" which allow one to scroll a configurable size of screen definable in the usual IDEA settings dialog.

There's an installable version of the plugin in [official JetBrains repository](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11952-partial-navigation).

Comment: Great, but if you are on a mac you can get this behaviour globally, not just in Intellij, which is the solution i ended up with. Smooth too.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, or the question should be changed to reflect that it was about changing macOS behaviour and not the Intellij development interface. As it stands the accepted answer, and intended question is more suited for: superuser.com

Comment: Unfortunately, the plugin is not working since 2022.1 :( Here is [the tracking issue with a workaround for Mac users](https://github.com/andreycizov/idea-partialnav/issues/12)

Comment: @Agat there is an alternative plugin - Partial Page Scrolling - based on this plugin now available [in the store](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/23332-partial-page-scrolling)

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to control this through the settings. What you can do is write a plugin that performs scrolling in the way that you prefer. It's fairly easy: all you need to do is copy the existing [PageUpAction](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/platform-impl/src/com/intellij/openapi/editor/actions/PageUpAction.java)/[PageDownAction](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/platform-impl/src/com/intellij/openapi/editor/actions/PageDownAction.java) classes and the methods they call ([EditorActionUtil](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/platform-impl/src/com/intellij/openapi/editor/actions/EditorActionUtil.java).moveCaretPageUp/Down) to scroll by as much as you want.

Comment: Thanks, I am using Intellij 14 now, how do I create a new plugin? Can't see it in the new project window.

Comment: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Getting+Started+with+Plugin+Development

Comment: Great, thanks. I should also like to highlight another issue regarding this. When you page up up all the way up, the pointer moves to the beginning of the file. Page down then leads the pointer not being in the correct place. So if you are scrolled down a bit in the beginning of the document, and page up, look for something and then page down, you loose the place you were in. Very annoying.

Comment: @momomo  Did you end up creating that plugin? I'd be interested in it ;)

Comment: @javadba no i did not. I approached it a bit differently though. I successfully manipulated the page up/down globally on my mac to mouse scroll the size i want instead (smoothly as well!) so solved it globally rather than just for intellij.

Comment: I can definitely tell you that standard behaviour is not desired. There  is no reason why it should cut of exactly half a page. I can hold down page down and it will actually kind of scroll now and increase speed.

Comment: @javadba I added a new answer for mac users.